# python script indentation in different editors

Tags: python, emacs

I use emacs-w32 on windows to edit some python scripts. the script file looks like this and works totally fine.

```
def methodA():
    i=1
    j=1
```

But when I open it using notepad++ (yes, use it sometimes still, as open emacs costs quite some time ).  it looks like this:

```
def methodA():
i=1
j=1
```

it actually still works.  how does indentation actually work in python ? and how to make they look the same in both editors ?

Comment: Is the second example really completely unindented? It's most likely a tab/spaces mix of indentation between editors.

Comment: Use `server-mode` and `emacsclient` to eliminate the starting time.

Comment: that's why you shouldn't use tabs for indentation. Use 4 spaces, that looks in every editor the same. (And really you can set tab-width to 0 in notepad++?)

Comment: @choroba it's my personal PC, which get rebooted every day. I am using alexott/emacs-configs which makes the editor slow.

Comment: @zinking While ignoring the precice stuff mentioned: A way to fasten Emacs loading config is to put that stuff into commands. Commonly you don't need all of it all the time. Than run command by command afterward, the moment you need it.

Comment: The tabs/spaces argument is usually an opinion-based flamewar, but with Python the official style guide [says to use four spaces for indentation](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: @zinking: I use `server-mode` on my personal PC and laptop, too.